# Indonesian Passport - Travelling to Hong Kong close to the six-month expiration date

Tags: visas, passports, hong-kong, indonesia, expired

My passport will expire on November 11, 2024.

If I enter HK on May 1st, leave HK on May 7th, and enter Jakarta the next day, will this be an issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

> Will this be an issue?

No. In general, all visitors to Hong Kong must have a passport that is valid for at least one month after the period of their intended stay in Hong Kong.

Source: [Hong Kong Tourism Board: Immigration & Customs](https://www.discoverhongkong.com/uk/plan/traveller-info/immigrations-and-customs.html)

Comment: I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @user139914 Click the ✔️ mark to accept the answer if it worked for you!